# Does uninstall a plugin causes in Jenkins/Hudson job config file to lose its plugin changes?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

We are trying to troubleshoot why our job config page is not loading.
If we uninstall each plugin as we troubleshoot, would Hudson or Jenkins modify the job config files that had previously used those installed plugins
and remove those plugins tags just because we uninstalled them temporarily ?
We ask because we like to know if we need to make job config backups as we do not want to lose the old installed plugin tags used in our jobs.

Thank you
Sincerely

Comment: There is an option in the global config to remove data relating to uninstalled plugins. It comes up at the top of the page. I don't think you will be able to run jobs if the XML cannot be parsed. It might be better to have a test version of Jenkins running so you don't impact a live system

Comment: Hi KeepCalmAndCarryOn, thanks for responding. We're not sure where within the global config you are referring to in Hudson and Jenkins. Would you elaborate more ?

Comment: Hi I think this should be the link (well its mine, anyway) http://localhost:8080/administrativeMonitor/OldData/manage

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be doing job config backups! Yes, you probably should rsync your job config data and jenkins directories sans workspaces to a different system for debugging.

No, when you uninstall a plugin, the data that is associated with that plugin is generally left behind, **unless you modify a job afterwards.**

Comment: Hi Electrawn, thanks for responding. So to recap, you are saying that the uninstalled plugin tags would still remain in the job config file, right ?